# Python and Tkinter - write to file matrix made from button grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, tkinter, grid

It's my first time coding in Python and I have a Tkinter grid with 5 x 5 buttons:

```
from tkinter import *
class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.TopFrame = Frame(root)
        self.BottomFrame = Frame(root)
        self.TopFrame.grid(row=0)
        self.BottomFrame.grid(row=6)

        buttonQ = Button(self.BottomFrame, text="Quit", command=quit)
        buttonS = Button(self.BottomFrame, text="Save", command=self.saveToFile())
        buttonS.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
        buttonQ.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

def Function(self):
    self.grid = []
    for i in range(5):
        row = []
        for j in range(5):
            row.append(Button(self.TopFrame,width=6,height=3,command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.getClick(i, j),background='gray'))
            row[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
        self.grid.append(row)

def getClick(self, i, j):
    orig_color = self.grid[i][j].cget('bg')
    if orig_color=="red":
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="gray"
    else:
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="red"

def saveToFile(self):
    myFile=open("example.txt", 'w')
    for line in range(5):
        for column in range(5):
            bg_color = self.grid[line][column].cget('bg')
            if bg_color == "red":
                myFile.write("1 ")
            else:
                myFile.write("0 ")
        myFile.write("\n")
    myFile.close()
    myFile = open("example.txt",'r')
    print(myFile.read())

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.Function()
root.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to write a matrix in a .txt file based on the colours of the buttons from the grid (0 if grey and 1 if red, with spaces between columns and each row on a new line) but I get this errors and I don't know why:

```
File "C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\PyPlay\ExampleTkinter.py", line 47, in <module>
app = App(root)
 File "C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\PyPlay\ExampleTkinter.py", line 12, in __init__
    buttonS = Button(self.BottomFrame, text="Save", command=self.saveToFile())
  File "C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\PyPlay\ExampleTkinter.py", line 33, in saveToFile
    myFile=open("example.txt", 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'example.txt'
```

I've tried changing the filename, adding the full path `C:\Users\Dana\Desktop\PyPlay\example.txt` but the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1.

```
command=self.saveToFile()
```

Should be changed to:

```
command=self.saveToFile
```

Or else command will be equalled to the return value of the function, which is None.

2.

Either you opened the example.txt file somewhere else, in which you forgot to close it. Or you do not have permission to create files or the file has permission settings that prevents user from changing it. Try running as administrator.

Comment: I've made the changes according to your answer and I didn't get any error. It printed the correct matrix but when I opened the file there was no content in it :( It's my write to file bad in code?

Comment: No, it's fine, preferably you add a myFile.close() after you print it, and using with syntax is always preferred.

Comment: Tried that and same thing... :( don't know why